# Greenish printing in grayscale mode

Tags: printing, colors

I have a `HP OfficeJet 7310` printer at home. It's about 6 years old and still functioning... "good".

Good quoted because I recently noticed that grayscale prints result a little "greenish". Greys look a little green instead of pure old grey.

Recently I started buying cheaper refilled cartridges for the printer, at least to try the cheap solution to my rare printing. I also tried to clean the cartridges several times but the problem persists. I don't know if providing a scanned sample is of help, but anyway my question is: since I explicitly set the printer to grayscale mode, and provided that colour printing is fine even with the refilled cartridge (with the exception of a few horizontal white lines caused by bad quality of cartridge that will be replaced with an original as soon as it depletes), why does the printer use colours from colour cartridge to print grey tones that result a little "greenish"?

The problem occurs even if I accidentally forget the photo cartridge inserted in the black slot

Could it be a problem with the printer, the cartridges or even the paper (100 g/sqm printer paper bought 1+1/2 year ago)

By the way, I'm not printing frequently as I'm using more and more electronic documents (except for photos, but that's another matter).

Just for completeness, here are cartridge numbers I use:

- Black: 339 (original)
- Colour: 344 (refilled)
- Photo: 348 (original)

The cartridge slots are following: left for colour or photographic grey (I don't own one), right for black or photographic hexachromy. Both slots must be filled with a cartridge or the printer won't work

Comment: Often such issues with non-OEM cartridges.

Comment: But the black is original

Comment: Just to make sure, try removing the color cartridge and printing greyscale again. Do you still see the green tinge?

Comment: The printer won't work without the colour cartridge installed